# Space in the Canon BG-E9 battery grip for ... something?

Tags: canon, battery-grip

I was cleaning my Canon 60D camera house and everything, and I took off the battery grip to make sure there wasn't any dust or whatnot inside.

Then I noticed something, there seems to be set aside space on the arm that sticks into the camera house for ... something.

Does anyone know if that is correct, and then what that "something" is?

Here's pictures of the space:

[image: space in bg-e9 battery grip, image #1]
[image: space in bg-e9 battery grip, image #2]

There's even some small "arm" that I would gather something would fit behind, perhaps to hold it in place. It doesn't fit anything inside the camera house so it doesn't appear to have any purpose at all. You see that "arm" best on the second photo.

The small light gray square block extruding in the lower right corner of the area (best visible on the first photo, to the left of the arrow pointing left around the center of the photo) is a rubberlike block of foam, again supporting my theory that something is meant to be fastened in here.

There doesn't seem to be any way to connect anything to power or the camera itself though, so I don't understand what it could be.

Do you?

Comment: why does it even matter?

Comment: It doesn't? I was just interested. It caught my eye so I thought I'd ask. To be honest I like to know everything there is about the tools I use, so this was just a little mystery to me.

Comment: @MichaelNielsen - in this case it matters since it is a significant feature for making sure you don't lose parts of your camera. It also illustrates the advantage of reading the manual to figure out all there is to know about tools. :)

Comment: A serious case of RTFM I fear... :-/

Comment: Nice bokeh. hehe

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The battery door.  This is where the door that is normally on the camera goes while you have the battery grip on the camera.  That way, when you remove the grip, you can easily put the door back on without losing it.

The [manual](http://a248.e.akamai.net/pix.crutchfield.com/Manuals/280/280BGE9.PDF) shows how it works.

Comment: I was probably a bit too eager when unpacking everything last year to actually read that manual :) The battery door fit nicely in there. When taking the picture of the battery grip, I actually had to go find the box the camera came in to find the battery door to get the camera to turn on, yet it still didn't register with me that the little illustration with the arrow was of the battery door. I went through the manual now, just to make sure there wasn't any other surprises, and lo and behold, I finally figured out why there was a small rubberized "flap" where the batteries went in :) Thanks!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - yeah, I almost missed it when I got my battery grip as well.  Luckily the battery grip got to me before the camera itself so I had nothing better to do than look at it and read the manual.  I've the the one for the 5D Mark iii, but it has the same feature in the same place.